# not opening file in visual studio windows

Tags: c++, uwp

I am running Windows 10 and using VS2017. The code below is not opening a file...

```
    std::ofstream output_file;
    output_file.open("datafile.txt", std::ios::out);
    if (!output_file.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "This is the whole problem";
    }
```

Could this be related to permission to writing/reading file and how can I give it the permission.

Comment: Where is the file located?  MSVS typically uses the location where the source files reside as the working directory for the executable.

Comment: below is the file location and yes this is also where the executable is located. C:\Program Files (x86)\libmuse_6.0.3\windows\examples\x64\Debug\GettingData\AppX

Comment: You should move the file to wherever the source file is then and try again.  Most likely that is your issue.  That, or you could fully qualify the path like `output_file.open("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\libmuse_6.0.3\\windows\\examples\\x64\\Debug\\GettingData\\AppX\\datafile.txt", std::ios::out);`.

Comment: yes that's where the file is located. the full path doesn't work either.

Comment: If the full path does not work then it is probably a permissions issue.

Comment: would you have any recommendations on resolving/troubleshooting permission issue since it doesn't get caught as an error?

Comment: Just a long shot : Did you create your project and /or solution with VS running as Administrator and now you're testing as normal user ?

Comment: @engf-010 i think so

Comment: If you did ,that could explain it ! Just rename the old solution/project ,make a new solution/project with VS running as normal user and copy your sources, headers ,resources to the newly created directory(directories). Rebuild and test again. But before you do that you'd better test again with VS running as administrator !

Answer (score 0):

In UWP app, it can access certain file system locations by default. It can also access additional locations through the [file picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers), or by declaring [capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations). You can see the [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) topic for details.

For your issue, it seems you want to access the file in your app InstalledLocation, as the [Application install directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#application-install-directory) introduction, you can access the file using the following code in C++/WinRT:

```
Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction ExampleCoroutineAsync()
{
    Windows::Storage::StorageFile file{
        co_await Windows::Storage::StorageFile::GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(Windows::Foundation::Uri{L"ms-appx:///datafile.txt"})
    };
    // Process file
}
```

Or C++:

```
auto getFileTask = create_task(StorageFile::GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(ref new Uri("ms-appx:///datafile.txt")));
getFileTask.then([](StorageFile^ file) 
{
    // Process file
});
```